# PHP Curl to API

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm trying to write a custom web interface for my wifi pineapple nano. I am not an experienced coder or anything, but I know and somewhat understand php and decided to use php curl to talk to the build in REST API on the pineapple.

I've written the following code:

```
?php
print "your code started</br>";

$key="7de64925dd8703fc5595a7d0b845ce0ed965fa799b67a19b310cb2538017aeaacb205e6dbc72d8758c3b995d25a1a273783c49bfb7519b2e71fbd49af074ab35";

//define and encode json
/*$a = new \stdClass();
$a->module="Filters";
$a->action="addClient";
$a->mac="c0:ee:fb:4a:c1:57";
$a->apiToken=$key;
 */

$a=[
        'system'=>'notifications',
        'action'=>'addNotification',
        'message'=>'Hello from apache!',
        'apiToken'=>'7de64925dd8703fc5595a7d0b845ce0ed965fa799b67a19b310cb2538017aeaacb205e6dbc72d8758c3b995d25a1a273783c49bfb7519b2e71fbd49af074ab35'

   ];
    $JSON = json_encode($a);
    print $JSON;
    //curl post request
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "172.16.42.1/api");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $JSON);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: ' . $key
    ));

    //print curl output
    $result = curl_exec($c);
    print $result;
    $info = curl_getinfo($c);
print '</br>';
print $info['http_code'];
if(!curl_exec($c)){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($c) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($c));
}
//close curl request
        curl_close($c);
        //debug
print "</br>Your code ran";
```

On execution I get the following output:

> your code started
>   {"system":"notifications","action":"addNotification","message":"Hello
>   from
>   apache!","apiToken":"7de64925dd8703fc5595a7d0b845ce0ed965fa799b67a19b310cb2538017aeaacb205e6dbc72d8758c3b995d25a1a273783c49bfb7519b2e71fbd49af074ab35"}
>   200Error: "" - Code: 0

However, on the pineapple there's nothing happening. When I look at the data through wireshark, I get a lot of ' 301 moved permanently' packages.

Anyone know the answer to this, or maybe a better way of doing what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

FYI: The curl request works in both CLI and postman, there doesn't seem to be any problem using these methods.

Comment: you're missing a closing ']' for $a

Comment: thanks to CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, you can't use `!` to check if curl_exec failed. curl_exec return bool(false) if there was an error, but it the response is empty, but no error occured, it returns an empty string, which ! also casts to bool(false), you must check the if curl_exec failed by doing `if(false===curl_exec($c)){`, also, don't discard the output of curl_exec, var_dump it. `if(false===($response=curl_exec($c))){`  and `var_dump($response);`

Comment: maybe problem is

--- 172.16.42.1 ping statistics ---

16 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 14999ms

Comment: @buildok, this IP is a local IP connected to the wifi pineapple. The connections works, same for the curl request when done via CLI or postman, believe me: I made sure more than a few times!

Comment: @inneedofhelp thanks, it was a copy paste error. Edited it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, a lot was unnecesary code and I missed the port that needs to be defined in the url. Working code is as follows:

```
<?php
print "your code started</br>";

//define JSON
$a=[
    'system'=>'notifications',
    'action'=>'addNotification',
    'message'=>'Hello from apache!',
    'apiToken'=>'apikey123'
];

//encode JSON
$JSON = json_encode($a);
print $JSON;

//curl post request
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://172.16.42.1:1471/api/");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $JSON);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
));

//print curl output
$result = curl_exec($c);
if($result === false){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($c) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($c));
}
print $result;
$info = curl_getinfo($c);
print '</br>';
print $info['http_code'];

//close curl request
    curl_close($c);
    //debug
print "</br>Your code ran";
?>
```

Thanks to everybody who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 "curl_exec" in your code

i'm not sure it's a good way to code :)

if you look at the end of your log you have

200Error: "" - Code: 0

at least correct this

```
$result = curl_exec($c);
    print $result;
    $info = curl_getinfo($c);
print '</br>';
print $info['http_code']; // (it displays http 200 : it works)
if(!curl_exec($c)){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($c) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($c));
}
```

to

```
if(!($result = curl_exec($c))){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($c) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($c));
}
print $result;
$info = curl_getinfo($c);
print '</br>';
print $info['http_code'];
```

2nd edit : have you tried changing http_header ?

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: ' . $key
    ));
```

to

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'accept: application/json',
            'Authorization: ' . $key
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks! Commented out the last one, but still no luck :(

Comment: No succes on all of these answers, starting to think somehow the routing doesn't work or something. Weird..

Comment: Well, I guess not. Unplugging returns the correct error statement so the 200 'must be correct too'

Answer (score 0):

PHP curl might not follow redirections without you specifing it with this :

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: correct, curl doesn't. OP has CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION commented-out in his code tho

Comment: True, however, I found putting this in doesn't change the output or result

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Content-Length` header:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: ' . $key,
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $JSON ) // <----
));
```

Add the scheme to the URL:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://172.16.42.1/api");
```

Remove/comment this

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

As you already set `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`

Fix the double `curl_exec`: instead of `if(!curl_exec($c)){`

```
if( $result === false ) {
```

---

Anyway your code seem working as the server returns a status code `200`.

(No errors, no redirects).

**Double check it actually produces no result on the destination server.**

Comment: Thanks for the help!

The URL is, I believe, already added. I double checked, but still no luck..